# Points not intersecting when they should

Tags: postgis, polygon

I'm new to postgis and I'm trying to show that a point intersects a polygon.

However, no matter how hard I try I can't.

Here is the point: 0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF629EA494D7BB4940

Here is the polygon: https://mapit.mysociety.org/area/65731.wkt

I'm trying:

```
SELECT st_contains('0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF629EA494D7BB4940',geom), name FROM table;
```

Where geom is the column with all the polygons.

As a note, the polygons are multipolygons in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Point and the Polygon have different coordinate systems:

The Point in WKT:

```
POINT(-0.157703161239624 51.4675164989283)
```

These are Lat/Lon Coordinates (maybe [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326)).
The Polygon has a different coordinate system:

```
POLYGON((526640 176973 [...]))
```

It seems to be [EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700) (OSGB 1936 / British National Grid)

So your correct call would be:

```
SELECT 
  st_intersects(
    ST_Transform('0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF629EA494D7BB4940'::geometry, 27700),
    geom
  ),
name
FROM table;
```

OR you could use the [API](https://mapit.mysociety.org/docs/#api-by_area_id) to get EPSG:4326 polygons:
https://mapit.mysociety.org/area/4326/65731.wkt

[image]

Comment: I tried `SELECT st_contains(ST_Transform('0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF629EA494D7BB4940', 27700),geom), name FROM table;` but it has the error `Error: function st_transform(unknown, integer) is not unique`. Any ideas?

Comment: you might need to cast the string as geometry => `'0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF‌​629EA494D7BB4940'::geometry`. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's still resulting in no results. I downloaded the dataset from here https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html. Then imported with `shp2pgsql westminster_const_region.shp public.westminster > areas.sql` and then run the above query and I don't get anything.

Comment: Also, when I query `SELECT
ST_SRID(geom),
name
FROM westminster;` then the SRID of the imported geom is `0`

Comment: Update the SRID of the geom column: `SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('westminster','geom',27700);`

Comment: Ok - I've run `SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('westminster','geom',27700);` which results in `SELECT ST_SRID(geom) = 27700`. Then I run `SELECT name
FROM westminster
WHERE st_contains(ST_Transform('0101000020E6100000000000009E2FC4BF629EA494D7BB4940'::geometry, 27700), geom);` Where the geom that I'm expecting to see is https://pastebin.com/Z7UhtQ1i. Yet I don't get any results.

Comment: OK - I seemed to have solved it by using `ST_Intersects` instead of `ST_Contains` - That and updating the geometry SRID and then transforming the point. Thanks!!